# Varied amounts of input data

Tags: java

**Problem:** Statistics are often calculated with varying amounts of input data. Write a program that takes any number of non-negative integers as input, and outputs the average and max. A negative integer ends the input and is not included in the statistics.

Ex: When the input is:
15 20 0 5 -1

the output is:
10 20

You can assume that at least one non-negative integer is input.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);
      int num = 0;
      int count = 0;
      int max = 0;
      int total = 0;
      int avg = 0;

     do {

         total += num;
         num = scnr.nextInt();
         count = ++count;


         if (num >= max) {
            max = num;
         }

      } while (num >= 0);

     avg = total/(count-1);

      System.out.println(avg + " " + max);

   }
}
```

I had a lot of trouble with this problem. Is there any way I could have done this without having to do count -1 while computing the average?
Also, is this this the most efficient way I could have done it?

Comment: This is wrong `count = ++count;`  Read it carefully.  Break it down.   It should be `count += 1;` or `count++;`

Comment: Also, `avg` should be a floating point number, and the computation to compute it should be done with floating point division,

Comment: For the purpose of this assignment, avg was always going to be an integer. ZyBooks wouldn't accept it if it was a double. Also, I realised I had already initialized count and could just do count++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? If you have questions from the implementation, please ask.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0, max = 0, total = 0;

        int num = scnr.nextInt();
        while (num >= 0) {
            count++;
            total += num;
            max = Math.max(max, num);
            num = scnr.nextInt();
        }

        int avg = count == 0 ? 0 : total/count;
        System.out.println(avg + " " + max);
    }
```

If you use while loop instead of do-while loop, you don't have to count the negative number input anymore. And no, it's not the most efficient way, but it's a good start!

Comment: I was having so many issues becasue I had forgotten I needed to get the input both before and inside the loop! Thank you for your help! Also, I'm not able to use Math.max since we haven't gone over that in class yet. Can you explain what "int avg = count == 0 ? 0 : total/count;" does? We haven't gone over that yet either.

Comment: Great! 
int avg = count == 0 ? 0 : total/count; means:
```java
int avg;
if (count == 0)
 avg = 0;
else
 avg = total/count;
```

Comment: ? : are java conditional operators that you can use to "shortcut" your statements

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);
      int userNum;
      int maxNum = 0;
      int totalSum = 0;
      int averageNum;
      int count = 0;

      userNum = scnr.nextInt();

      while (userNum >= 0) {

         if (userNum > maxNum) {
            maxNum = userNum;
         }

         totalSum += userNum;
         ++count;

         userNum = scnr.nextInt();
      }
      averageNum = totalSum / count;

      System.out.println("" + averageNum + " " + maxNum);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      int Num;
      int max = 0;
      int total = 0;
      int average;
      int count = 0;

      Num = scnr.nextInt();

      while (Num >= 0) {

         if (Num > max) {
            max = Num;
         }

         total += Num;
         ++count;

         Num = scnr.nextInt();
      }
      average = total / count;

      System.out.println("" + average + " " + max);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation on the given code, telling why you code solve the problem.

Comment: I find it hard to see any improvement, except some renamed variables. How did this pass the review? The funny thing is, that I just watched the AlphaGo documentary and then this avatar of your's.